# IIS Can't Serve .LDF or .MDF extensions

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to serve the extensions .ldf and .mdf and even though files of these types actually exist on the server, IIS keeps throwing 404 error whenever they are requested.

I've double checked IIS manager and both extensions are added MIME-types of application/octet_stream. Is there perhaps some other setting or place I've missed that needs something set?

Thanks for your help chaps.

Comment: There are some extensions that are disabled by default. You can override it in web.config and here is an example: http://serverfault.com/questions/163396/which-file-extensions-are-always-going-to-be-ok-with-iis

Comment: Thanks. All is working well now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to web.config worked as suggested by Sergey Kornilov:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions>
      <remove fileExtension=".ldf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".mdf" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```